# Reset last draw graphics on text change

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a four text boxes for draw rectangle which is x,y,height and width and i want to draw rectangle on text change but the Rectangle is not drawn when i reset a image ( `picturebox1.Image = bkp ) what i am doing wrong help me guyz?

```
if (txtHeight.Text != "" && txtLeftMargin.Text != "" && txtTopMargin.Text != "" && txtWidth.Text != "")
            {
            pictureBox1.Image = bkp;
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
            Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, Convert.ToInt16(txtLeftMargin.Text), Convert.ToInt16(txtTopMargin.Text), Convert.ToInt16(txtHeight.Text), Convert.ToInt16(txtWidth.Text));

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
   Image backgroundImage = (Image)bkp.Clone();

   using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(backgroundImage))
   using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red))
   {
      gfx.DrawRectangle(pen,
                        Convert.ToInt16(txtLeftMargin.Text),
                        Convert.ToInt16(txtTopMargin.Text),
                        Convert.ToInt16(txtHeight.Text),
                        Convert.ToInt16(txtWidth.Text));
   }

   pictureBox1.Image = backgroundImage;
```

Check that the **"bkp"** -image isn't empty and that it's bigger than 1x1, or you can't see a thing. Otherwise it should work. I tested it with **"Image.FromFile()"**, where I loaded an image from my HDD to **"backgroundImage"**-variable. The dimensions of the image set the maximum draw area.

Comment: actually this code is not working on text change and the same code work fine on Button Click !

Comment: I made 4 textBoxes, marginleft, margintop, and posleft, posright, all linked to the same "TextChanged"-method. I used the same code as above, except the "Image.FromFile"-thing. I also used Trim() while reading the values: marginleft.Text.Trim() != "". I couldn't paste the whole code as SO gave me error. **There's something else in the TextChanged-event that's causing problems**

Comment: then mail me @ faysal_ubit@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

As so many others you don't draw the right way:

Everything you draw in winforms must either be drawn in the control's `paint` event or be triggered from there. So you must:

- keep the geometry data for your `Rectangle` from the textchange event somewhere (if that is what you are doing),
- put the drawing in the `paint` event (using the `e.Graphics` from the event argument) and
- trigger it by `invalidating` the control..